# Prove that $\mathcal{U}$ is NOT a topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that $\mathcal{U}_{1}=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(-\infty,x];x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is NOT a topology in $X=\mathbb{R}$

First I tried to prove that $\mathcal{U}_{2}=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(-\infty,x);x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a topology: The first two points are easy to see and I wanna make sure that the last one is ok:

Let $\{A_{j}:j\in J\}$a family of subsets of $\mathcal{U}_{2}$ where $A_{i}=\{(-\infty,i):i\in \mathbb{N}\}\subseteq \mathcal{U}_{2}$ then $\cup_{j\in J}A_{j}=\cup_{j\in J}\{(-\infty,j):j\in \mathbb{N}\}=\{(-\infty,k);k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $k>j$for all $j\in J$ and it´s easy to see that $\{(-\infty,k);k\in \mathbb{N}\}\subseteq\{\mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(-\infty,x);x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ then $\cup_{j\in J}A_{j}\subseteq \mathcal{U}_{2}$

Is this proof ok?

Can I use it to prove that $\mathcal{U}_{1}=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(-\infty,x];x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is NOT a topology in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You cannot use your proof about the one topology to prove that the other set is not a topology. Also, your proof that the other set is a topology is insufficient, because you must prove the third point for $\textbf{arbitrary}$ unions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you proved that other thing is a topology. To show that $\mathcal{U}$ is not a topology, you can show the open sets aren't closed under unions. In particular $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-\infty, -1/n] = (-\infty,0) \not \in \mathcal{U}$.

Comment: They are two different exercises and I thought the first one might help

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Your welcome! Please accept the answer by clicking the check if your question has been resolved. It will make it so question will not show up as unresolved in the future.